# readyState=0 error when submitted form using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting the readyState=0 error when debugging using console.log(). The form is not sending the data to the php file.

```
Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(e), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(e, t), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(e), statusCode: statusCode(e), abort: abort(e), state: state(), always: always(), catch: catch(e)
, … }
​
readyState: 0
​
setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader()
​​
length: 2
​​
name: "setRequestHeader"
​​
prototype: Object { … }
​​
<prototype>: function ()
​
state: function state()
​
status: 0
​
statusCode: function statusCode()
​
statusText: "error"
​
then: function then()
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

this is the ajax code  that I have wrote for sending the data but the alert part is not working and error is shown I am unable to figure out why readyState is zero

```
function send_message() {
  var name = jQuery("#name").val();
  var email = jQuery("#email").val();
  var mobile = jQuery("#mobile").val();
  var message = jQuery("#message").val();
  console.log("in function")

  if (name == "") {
    alert('Please enter name');
  } else if (email == "") {
    alert('Please enter email');
  } else if (mobile == "") {
    alert('Please enter mobile');
  } else if (message == "") {
    alert('Please enter message');
  } else {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'send_message.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&mobile=' + mobile + '&message=' + message,
      success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });

  }
}
```

P.S i shortened the error message due to stackoverflow code limit
I want to get it done using JavaScript but getting error in ajax.send()

```
else{
 var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "send_message.php", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // Response
        var response = this.responseText;
        console.log(response);
        alert(response);
      }
    };
    var data = {'name':name,'email':email,'mobile':mobile,'message':message};
    ajax.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Comment: You probably did not cancel the form submission.

Comment: How do you call send_message?

Comment: I submitted it by clicking the send button but php page is not connected to it where I wrote the insert queries

Comment: Show how you're connecting the function to the button.

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Send Message"  onclick="send_message()" class="btn" />
                </form>

Comment: using this code

Comment: `<input type="submit"` <-- submits the form, change it to button type or cancel the form submission.

Comment: ok let me try this

Comment: Well did it make a difference?

Comment: It worked but I want to do it using javaScript bhut getting undefined index error

Comment: Kindly read my edited part